# Assign one class module sub to multiple OptionButtons vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm dynamically creating option buttons on a form in Microsoft Word. I programatically assign the new options buttons a sub by way of the code below, but I can't work out how to assign one class to many buttons. Is this possible?

The code below works, but it only throws the message box up on the last button. I think what my code is doing is reassigning this class to the newest button each time, rather than adding a button to that class if that makes sense? How would I go about doing it the other way around so many buttons call the Focus_btn_Click event?

My Class (called "clsSectorbtn"):

```
Public WithEvents Focus_btn As MSForms.OptionButton
Sub Focus_btn_Click()
    Msgbox "Test"
End Sub
```

Code within my form:

```
Dim SectorBtn As New clsSectorBtn    
Sub Create_Radios(Radio_Array)
    Dim RadioArray (0 to 2) As String
    RadioArray(0) = "optionbutton1"
    RadioArray(1) = "optionbutton2"
    RadioArray(2) = "optionbutton3"
    Set Fm = UserForm1("Frame1")

    For x = 0 To UBound(Radio_Array)
        Set opt = Fm.Object.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1")
        opt.Caption = Radio_Array(x)
        Set SectorBtn.Focus_btn = opt
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a global collection to hold the instances of `clsSectorbtn`, and it's easier to use a "factory" function to build each instance.

I'd do something like this:

```
Dim colBtn As Collection    

Sub Create_Radios(Radio_Array)
    Dim RadioArray (0 to 2) As String
    RadioArray(0) = "optionbutton1"
    RadioArray(1) = "optionbutton2"
    RadioArray(2) = "optionbutton3"
    Set Fm = UserForm1("Frame1")

    Set colBtn = New collection
    For x = 0 To UBound(Radio_Array)
        Set opt = Fm.Object.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1")
        opt.Caption = Radio_Array(x)
        colBtn.Add OptObject(opt)
    Next x
End Sub

'create an instance of clsSectorbtn and assign an option button to it
Function OptObject(opt) As clsSectorbtn
    Dim rv as New clsSectorbtn
    Set rv.Focus_btn = opt
    Set OptObject = rv
End Function
```